# Check if case-insensitive string exist in List

Tags: c#

I have an error with my List. Let me show you my idea: I have a loop, when finish loop 1, value will add to List, and it will continue when finish loop. Finally, i will a List that include all value in each loop.

Then, i want to check if value is exist in List. If exist, i will do something.

Example:

> Loop 1: List: A
>
> Loop 2: List: A,B
>
> Loop 3: List: A,B,A

Because value A is Exist in List. Then, i will do some thing if A exist in List

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
{
  string Url = r["Url"].ToString();
  list.Add(Url);
  if (list.Contains(Url, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
      //dosomething
    }
}
```

But nothing happen. Wish you help me improve my code. Thanks !!!

Comment: Why are you adding `Url` to `list` and then immediately check if `list` contains the string you just added?

Comment: Hi Brian, because i must use other system that give me a link. And i must develop base on position. It's very hard to show you my system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this

```
if(list.Where(o=> string.Equals(Url, o, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Any())
{
   // Exists in the list
}
```

Or

```
if(list.FindIndex(o=> string.Equals(Url, o, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))>-1){

  // Exists in the list
}
```

Comment: This would be a good approach in case OP wants to check the multiple occurrence, else we have Exists / Contains, in fact code in the if block will not help in using the Count of the IEnumerable generated via Where, so will be of little use in the current form

Answer (score 5):

Better approach would be using the List methods `Exists` or `Contains`, checkout the following program:

```
List<string> l = new List<string>();
l.Add("Madrid");
l.Add("Barcelona");
l.Add("NewYork");
l.Add("Chicago");  
if(l.Exists(x=>string.Equals(x,"Chicago",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))){
    Console.WriteLine("Done !!");
}
```

In case of Exist, you can ignore the case using the `StringComparison` enumeration, but that's not the case for `Contains`, where you need to take care of the case, or else you need custom `IComparer` to ignore the case